# Spark: YARN throws NoSuchMethodError on NettyMemoryMetrics

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

In order to get Spark (spark-2.3.0-bin-without-hadoop) to work with YARN on a HDFS I downgraded Hadoop to hadoop-2.7.6 in order to solve dependency problems.

So far both HDFS and YARN start without problems.

When I submit a Spark Jar it crashes and I get the following Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.metric()Lio/netty/buffer/PooledByteBufAllocatorMetric;
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.NettyMemoryMetrics.registerMetrics(NettyMemoryMetrics.java:80)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.NettyMemoryMetrics.<init>(NettyMemoryMetrics.java:76)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.<init>(TransportClientFactory.java:109)
    at org.apache.spark.network.TransportContext.createClientFactory(TransportContext.java:99)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.<init>(NettyRpcEnv.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnvFactory.create(NettyRpcEnv.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv$.create(RpcEnv.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runExecutorLauncher(ApplicationMaster.scala:515)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$ApplicationMaster$$runImpl(ApplicationMaster.scala:347)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$2.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$2.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$2.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$5.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:800)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1758)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.doAsUser(ApplicationMaster.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:259)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:824)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:854)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
>
```

This happens both when I start my own programs and the examples provided by Spark.
I am pretty sure that I have my classpaths set correctly in spark-env.sh:

```
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop classpath):/usr/local/spark/jars/*
```

The generated classpath looks like this:

```
SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH='/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop//share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop//share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop//share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop//share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop//share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.6/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.6/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/hadoop//share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop//share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/usr/local/spark/jars/*'
```

I have no clue how to resolve this. Apart from a configuration problem my best guess would yet another library incompatibility.
In that case could anybody point me to a Spark/Hadoop combination that actually works without conflicts?

```
find . -name netty*
./spark-2.3.0-bin-without-hadoop/jars/netty-3.9.9.Final.jar
./spark-2.3.0-bin-without-hadoop/jars/netty-all-4.1.17.Final.jar
./hadoop-2.7.6/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar
./hadoop-2.7.6/share/hadoop/kms/tomcat/webapps/kms/WEB-INF/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar
./hadoop-2.7.6/share/hadoop/tools/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar
./hadoop-2.7.6/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar
./hadoop-2.7.6/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar
./hadoop-2.7.6/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar
./hadoop-2.7.6/share/hadoop/httpfs/tomcat/webapps/webhdfs/WEB-INF/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar
./hadoop-2.7.6/share/hadoop/httpfs/tomcat/webapps/webhdfs/WEB-INF/lib/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar
./hadoop-2.7.6/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar
```

Comment: After digging further I have narrowed down the problem. I commented out spark.yarn.jars in spark-defaults.conf and the error did not occur: The process finished correctly. I intercepted the zip-file that Spark creates and uploads to hdfs and the contents are identical to the contents of the folder that spark.yarn.jars pointed to before. This was true for every client machine as well. So I still have no idea why this problem occurs and how to get rid of it.

Comment: Have you solved this problem.  I am also getting the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem and the answer is embarrassingly simple: the `spark.yarn.jars` property didn't have to be set to `/usr/local/spark/jar` but to `/usr/local/spark/jar/*` and everything worked.